# How to specify line wrapping delimiter in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, delimiter

I have an EditText view which has'textMultiLine|textEmailAddress' inputType.
The idea is that users should be able to insert multiple emails there separated by commas(',').

Android's default points of wrapping lines are after dots, of course. But, in this case, it would be clearer to prefer wrapping lines after ',' (or '@') characters.

So, does anybody know if there a trivial solution to this problem?
I've spent a few hours searching for a solution
but I haven't even found anybody with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [textwatcher class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to insert newline characters were you require them maybe not exactly the way you want it but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's one option, but modifying the content when I just want to modify the view. It sounds that I might do an OK solution with that approach but I could forget something. Also, what if user would like to modify the emails. He/she might be surprised when finding newlines he/shed didn't put.

Comment: I was hoping to find a method such as: editText.setLineWrappingDelimiters(char[] delimitersInPriorityOrder);

Comment: I doubt that exists there's nothing like that in textview which is edittext's direct superclass so you may be stuck a hack